# Opening JSON files with function - JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, function, dataframe

> SUMMARY of problem:
> I am trying to build a small function to open JSON files in a directory but when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<input>", line 1, in <module

  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script

  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "Python script path redacted for privacy", line 58, in <module>
    df_meta = getDF(metadata_directory + file_metadata)

  File "Python script path redacted for privacy", line 36, in getDF
    for d in parse(path):

  File "Python script path redacted for privacy", line 27, in parse
    yield json.load(jsonfile)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 150)
```

> MORE DETAILS:

I have some json files that look like this:

```
{"id":"00610","title":"Workout Headphones","brand":"Collins","main_cat":"fashion","date":null,"description":null}
{"id":"01430","title":"Black Diamond","brand":"Swedish","main_cat":"fashion","date":null,"description":["some description","",""]}
{"id":"01478","title":"HEAVEN KAJAL\"HERBAL kajal","main_cat":"fashion","date":null,"description":["some description"]}
```

I built these two function to read the json files into DataFrames:

```
def parse(path):
    with open(path) as jsonfile:
        yield json.load(jsonfile)


def getDF(path):
    i = 0
    df = {}
    for d in parse(path):
        df[i] = d
        i += 1
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')
```

To open the dataframes I use the above function(s) with some paths:

```
df_m = getDF(folder_path + filename)
```

Everything looks fine to be but for some reason that error is appearing.
Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is not a valid JSON file, because a valid JSON file can only contain one single top object. **But** each line is a valid json string. So you should change your `parse` function:

```
def parse(path):
    with open(path) as jsonfile:
        for line in jsonfile:
            yield json.loads(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. Here is a nice site where you can check validity of any JSON: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Whats wrong in your instance is your JSON has multiple root elements which makes it invalid.

My suggestion would be to put those elements into a single list like so:

```
[
    {
        "id": "00610",
        "title": "Workout Headphones",
        "brand": "Collins",
        "main_cat": "fashion",
        "date": null,
        "description": null
    },
    {
        "id": "01430",
        "title": "Black Diamond",
        "brand": "Swedish",
        "main_cat": "fashion",
        "date": null,
        "description": [
            "some description",
            "",
            ""
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "01478",
        "title": "HEAVEN KAJAL\"HERBAL kajal",
        "main_cat": "fashion",
        "date": null,
        "description": [
            "some description"
        ]
    }
]
```